# Packaging Python code within repo for both internal and external use

Tags: python, pip

In our Python codebase, we have a module with several submodules, each of which we'd like to create a pip package for. The goal is to eventually get to a point where each of these submodule packages would be able to be distributed within our team, as well as to the public OSS community. Being new to Python packaging, I'm trying to figure out the best way to go about this, while still allowing us easy imports from within our non-packaged code in the same repo.

Currently, we have he pip setup done for each of the packages, but due to the nested folder structure, it makes the imports for these modules within our non-packaged code quite ugly.

What would be the best way to approach this?

Comment: Modules never contain each other. You should split them.

Comment: Your problems sound the same as the ones I've been struggling with recently, but I'm not sure what specific aspect you're asking for help with.  What does "quite ugly" mean in your case? What, specifically, is not happening the way you would ideally like?   Do you know about the `pip install -e` option?